# How do I use the tempstore service?

Tags: ajax

I'm storing some values in array and sending to the drupal through Ajax and receiving it through the controller. In the controller i am using the following code to retrieve and trying to store using the tempstore service.

```
$response_match = new JsonResponse();
    $checkedValueArray = \Drupal::request()->request->get('jsonCheckvalArr');
    $tempstore_factory_m = \Drupal::service('tempstore.private');
    $tempstore_m = $tempstore_factory_m->get('module_custom');
    $tempstore_m->set('my_variable_key1', $checkedValueArray);
    $data = ['message' => 'AJAX request received'];
    return new JsonResponse($response_match);
```

getting the following error.

```
Drupal\Core\TempStore\TempStoreException: Couldn't acquire lock to update item '1:my_variable_key1' in 'tempstore.private.module_custom' temporary storage. in Drupal\Core\TempStore\PrivateTempStore->set()
```

Can anyone figure out what exactly the error is?